# Flutter - HTML commands inside string variable

Tags: flutter, toast

I´m trying to configure html commands in this code:

```
String mytxt = '';
mytxt = Html(data: """<b>WARNING<b>\nVery important information!"""); // error in this line

Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: mytxt,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIos: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          textColor: Colors.black,);
```

Please, any tips?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: an error message would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse HTML, You can use the [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) library.

```
import 'package:html5lib/parser.dart' show parse;

parse('<b>WARNING<b>\nVery important information!');
```

However, it seems you are using the [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) library. As far as I can see from the docs, you can't use HTML in the `msg` property; it expects a string.